# CSS3: Hiding the parent div when the child div is visible

Tags: css, z-index

Beginner doubt: I would like to hide the parent div when the child div is visible. **Is this possible to do with css**? maybe using the z-index?

Another thing, Can I format the child div with different css atributes, or they need to be the same ones of the parent?
Thanks!

```
<!doctype html>
<style type="text/css">
#intro {
width:100%;
float:left;
padding-top:3%;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:100%;
position:relative;
z-index:50;
}       
.wrapper_intro {
display:block;
width:38%;
margin: 7% 3% 3% 7%;
float:right;
color:black;
padding:3% 3% 4% 3%;
background-color:none;
position:absolute;
z-index:100;
right: 0px;
}
.parent {
display:block;
font-size:5em;
 color:yellow;
margin-top: 2%;
margin-bottom:3%;
text-align:center;
z-index: 102;
}
.child {
display:none;
}
.parent:hover .child {
display:block;
background-color: rgba(242, 218, 192, 0.9);
margin-top:5%;
color:black;
text-align:center;
z-index: 101;
}

</style>
```

```
      <div class="wrapper_intro">

              <div class="parent">
                    <div>Ola!</div>

                    <div class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit     amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</div>
              </div>
```

Comment: 1. what means 'hide parent div' exactly? When the child has the same size, parent isn't visible (is in lower layer). 2. Child element can have different styles than paretn, of course. Any properties are inherited, there just set eg. default value to children.

Comment: Ok, maybe I m not using the right method. I want to have this word on a div, and when I hover it the word gets invisible, and another div with a text gets revealed.

Comment: Can you please show me an image how it looks? What div you want to hover and what div you want to show? Everything is possible, but please show me how it looks in default state, on what element you go with mouse and how looks the hover state.

Comment: Of course.
!(http://postimg.org/image/rwl23pvtb/) this the word I want, and when I hover it I reveal another text div !(http://postimg.org/image/qfwyg6zpr/f0a41ba3/).

I would like to hide the first div when the second one is visible.

Answer (score 0):

When you hide a parent div, all elements inside it also will get hidden.
Didn't understand ur scenario. If you want them to be separate, don't nest them in a div. Keep them separate.

Yes the css can be different for parent and child. You can use !important to over ride any css already used for parent.

Answer (score 0):

Due to comment it should be quite simply, what about adding just

```
.parent:hover > div:first-child {visibility: hidden}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/czd1z5jh/

OR if you want to move `.child` to the top:

```
.parent:hover > div:first-child {display: none}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/czd1z5jh/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot! that did the trick. 
Now I tried to change the font size of my child div to 1.5em using the !important, but I still wasn' t able to change it.

And If I want to make a more smoth transition on hiding the divs, any recommendation? I tried the -webkit-transition-delay: 1s on my .parent:hover > div:first-child class, but it did not worked